# How can I strip symbols from my executable when using Clang and the LLVM ELF ld.LLD linker?

Tags: hyperlink, clang, symbols, strip, lld

I am building with Clang 9.0.0 and linking with the ld.lld linker

```
clang++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -m64 -O3 -Xclang -flto-visibility-public-std -std=c++2a -flto=thin  -c
  I:\Cpp\hello_boost\hello_codeblocks_world\hello_codeblocks_world.cpp -o obj\release\hello_codeblocks_world.o

clang++.exe  -o bin\release\hello_codeblocks_world.exe obj\release\hello_codeblocks_world.o  -m64 -fuse-ld=lld --strip-all
```

but, unlike when using the usual GCC linker LD, this option (--strip-all or -s) is not recognized

```
clang++: error: unsupported option '--strip-all' (or similarly with -s)
```

Can anyone suggest what I should be doing to strip symbols?

(My release-mode  hello_world.exe size is 15 kb for GC but 230 kB for Clang :-( and this is likely to have some adverse effects for no benefit).

Is this not an option for ld.lld  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use:
-Xlinker --strip-all
`You can use this to supply system-specific linker options that GCC does not recognize` (gcc manual)
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html